# How to send an email to multiple receivers in opencart?

Tags: php, email, opencart, carbon-copy

This is how I'm currently sending notifications to the (two) admin of the shop

```
$mail = new Mail();
$mail->protocol = $this->config->get('config_mail_protocol');
$mail->parameter = $this->config->get('config_mail_parameter');
$mail->hostname = $this->config->get('config_smtp_host');
$mail->username = $this->config->get('config_smtp_username');
$mail->password = $this->config->get('config_smtp_password');
$mail->port = $this->config->get('config_smtp_port');
$mail->timeout = $this->config->get('config_smtp_timeout');     

$mailText = html_entity_decode($mailText,ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
/* Email para el admins Alcudia */
$mail->setFrom($this->request->post['email']);
$mail->setSender($this->request->post['name']);
$mail->setTo($admin_alcudia);
$mail->setSubject(html_entity_decode('Se ha realizado una solicitud de reserva', ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));
$mail->setHtml($mailText);
$mail->send();
/* Email para el admin de palma */
$mail->setFrom($this->request->post['email']);
$mail->setSender($this->request->post['name']);
$mail->setTo($admin_palma);
$mail->setSubject(html_entity_decode('Se ha realizado una solicitud de reserva', ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));
$mail->setHtml($mailText);
$mail->send();
```

The thing is that they're saying that the second one is not reciving it...

Any idea how to improve this? is there any CC functionality?

I've been waiting all day but http://docs.opencart.com/ won't get back to life..

Comment: I guess docs.opencart.com is down and will be replaced by https://support.opencart.com...

Comment: If You would look into some OpenCart's PHP code that sends email notifications, You would find out how easily this is done in OpenCart. Then `CTRL+C` and `CTRL+V` is the only things You need...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try separating the `sendTo()` function with commas in a string:

```
$mail = new Mail();

$mail->protocol = $this->config->get('config_mail_protocol');
$mail->parameter = $this->config->get('config_mail_parameter');
$mail->hostname = $this->config->get('config_smtp_host');
$mail->username = $this->config->get('config_smtp_username');
$mail->password = $this->config->get('config_smtp_password');
$mail->port = $this->config->get('config_smtp_port');
$mail->timeout = $this->config->get('config_smtp_timeout');     

$mailText = html_entity_decode($mailText,ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');

$mail->setFrom($this->request->post['email']);
$mail->setSender($this->request->post['name']);
$mail->setTo($admin_alcudia.','.$admin_palma);
$mail->setSubject(html_entity_decode('Se ha realizado una solicitud de reserva', ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));
$mail->setHtml($mailText);

$mail->send();
```

This should eliminate the need to have duplicate code.

Answer (score 2):

In OpenCart 2.x you need to pass in an array to the `setTo()` method.

```
$mail->setTo(array(0 => 'name@domain.com', 1 => 'name2@domain.com'));
```

Answer (score 0):

The other option is to not have to modify any code and to change it in the settings,

If you go to system and then into settings and then click edit on your store it will open up the settings for your store...

You then need to go across to the mail tab ans then scroll down to the "Additional Alert E-Mails" text box and then simply add the additional email address

No change in coding necessary...

Hope this helps,

Comment: Thanks - this is just what I was looking for. Not sure why this was marked down.

Answer (score 0):

OpenCart2

> /catalog/model/checkout/order.php ->
> addOrderHistory()

there is an additional script for sending additional addresses, which are configured in the 'Mail' tab

```
// this is the default code
    $mail = new Mail();
    $mail->protocol = $this->config->get('config_mail_protocol');
    $mail->parameter = $this->config->get('config_mail_parameter');
    $mail->smtp_hostname = $this->config->get('config_mail_smtp_hostname');
    $mail->smtp_username = $this->config->get('config_mail_smtp_username');
    $mail->smtp_password = html_entity_decode($this->config->get('config_mail_smtp_password'), ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
    $mail->smtp_port = $this->config->get('config_mail_smtp_port');
    $mail->smtp_timeout = $this->config->get('config_mail_smtp_timeout');

    $mail->setTo($this->config->get('config_email'));
    $mail->setFrom($this->config->get('config_email'));
    $mail->setSender(html_entity_decode($order_info['store_name'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));
    $mail->setSubject(html_entity_decode($subject, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));
    $mail->setHtml($this->load->view('mail/order', $data));
    $mail->setText($text);
    $mail->send();

// Send to additional alert emails
    $emails = explode(',', $this->config->get('config_alert_email'));

    foreach ($emails as $email) {
        if ($email && preg_match($this->config->get('config_mail_regexp'), $email)) {
            $mail->setTo($email);
            $mail->send();
        }
    }
// END this is the default code
```

As a result, you can make the following code

```
// added mailing from System->Setting->Store->E-Mail
    $mail2 = new Mail();
    $mail2->protocol = $this->config->get('config_mail_protocol');
    $mail2->parameter = $this->config->get('config_mail_parameter');
    $mail2->smtp_hostname = $this->config->get('config_mail_smtp_hostname');
    $mail2->smtp_username = $this->config->get('config_mail_smtp_username');
    $mail2->smtp_password = html_entity_decode($this->config->get('config_mail_smtp_password'), ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
    $mail2->smtp_port = $this->config->get('config_mail_smtp_port');
    $mail2->smtp_timeout = $this->config->get('config_mail_smtp_timeout');

    $mail2->setTo($this->config->get('config_email'));
    $mail2->setFrom($this->config->get('config_email'));
    $mail2->setSender(html_entity_decode($data['store_name'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));
    $mail2->setSubject(html_entity_decode($subject, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));
    $mail2->setHtml(html_entity_decode($html, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));
    $mail2->setText($text);
    $mail2->send();

    // Send to additional alert emails
    $emails = explode(',', $this->config->get('config_alert_email'));

    foreach ($emails as $email) {
      if ($email && preg_match($this->config->get('config_mail_regexp'), $email)) {
          $mail2->setTo($email);
          $mail2->send();
        }
      }
```

Comment: Hello, please don't post code only and add an explantation as to why you think that this is the optimal solution. People are supposed to learn from your answer, which might not occur if they just copy paste code without knowing why it should be used.

Comment: @Destroy666 There is not only code but also comments.
If a person knows even a little about OpenCart or he opens the file /catalog/model/checkout/order.php, then it will immediately become clear to him.
And if a person does not know PHP or OpenCart, then I will have to write a lot of text to teach someone))